# How to handle business logic errors and warnings, which chould/should be fixed in the current view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, warnings, business-logic

I'm working on an application where everything is going to be nicely separated. MVC and MVVM are being implemented.

What I would like to know is a nice clean way to handle business logic errors and warnings. And specifically the ones that could be handled by the current View. We're using Data Annotations to validate the ViewModel, but this doesn't cover everything, just the correctness of the ViewModel. The business rules should not be validated in the ViewModel, these are applied by the business layer. (e.g. checking for duplicate names).

How should we pass business logic errors and warnings from the business / service layer to the controllers?

If we'd use exceptions (icw HandleErrorAttribute) we'll have to implement part of the business logic in the controller which we don't really want. as in: the controller needs to be 'aware' of the business rules. And besides that this attribute want's to redirect us to another view.

I'm thinking about a BusinessResult class, but is this the right way to go?

Something like:

```
    class BusinessResult<T>
    {
        public T Result { get; }
        public bool HasErrors { get; }
        public bool HasWarnings { get; }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean if you use exceptions the controller will be aware of the business logic? Also, does your controller call the business layer or a web service and the service calls the business layer?

Comment: What I mean, part of the exceptions would be about businesslogic conflicts. e.g. DuplicateNameException But we could do a BusinessLogicException that carries error (and warning) descriptions. We don't want to handle business logic/rules specific exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: I would not do it that way.

Long answer:

My assumption is, since BusinessResult is generic, everyone of your services (or business methods but this is irrelevant) will return the BusinessResult but it will be closed i.e. `BusinessResult<SomeType>`.

1. This is not ideal. I rather look at a service or a method and know what it is returning to me specifically without having to read API documentation. For example,

   `public Customer GetCustomer(int customerId);`
2. The other issue you will face is that your calling code will always have to check HasErrors to determine if the service call was successful. You will have a lot of code which will be something similar:

   `var customer = GetCustomer(customerId);
   if (customer.HasErrors)
   {
       // Do something here...
   }
   else
   {
       // Proceed normally...
   }`
3. Furthermore, if the above code does not check for errors, then in a way it can go unnoticed until it pops up as some weird error to the end user.
4. The error, since it is not an exception, will not bubble up the call chain. If the caller has some code which handles all unhandled exceptions, it will not reach their for logging or some other purpose.
5. If you use some library on the web front such as jQuery, if the service returns HasError as true, it will still go into success

   `$.ajax({
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: success,
   dataType: dataType
   });`

   In the above in success you would need to check for HasError and ...you see where this is going.

If you look at the .NET framework, they have went through great lengths to avoid such a design. For example, this code will not return true or false (similar to your HasErrors flag):

```
var intValue = int.Parse("123");
```

It will return the parsed value if successful or throw an exception. They did this on purpose to force the caller to either handle the error or it will bubble up. They went even further and used the Try Pattern such as below:

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
if (result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
}
```

In a way, they are forcing the caller to play all these gymnastics with the out variable so their intention is very clear: I will not call the method which throws the exception but instead try this because I will check if the method returns a false and deal with it. Now the developer who wrote this calling code cannot make the innocent mistake of forgetting to check the success or failure; not if the developer wrote all that fancy (if I may) code.

In conclusion, I would follow the best practices: Try your best to return what you have promised and if there is an exceptional case, return an exception. If you are building RESTful services, follow their guidelines of returning HTTP error codes: Your clients will expect these error codes and they are familiar with them. If you are building WCF and not following RESTful, then throw fault exceptions: Your SOAP clients will be familiar with this. It will not be a little secret i.e. "Check the HasErrors flag every time you call my API".